# LG TV RS232 Control over rollover cable

Tags: ethernet, rs232, tv, rj45

My LG TV can be controlled over a RS232 port! The Problem is that  I don't have any serial devices to test it.

So my question is, can I do it with a rollover cable(RJ45 <--> D9)? 
I mean can I plug it into my Ethernetcard, start putty and communicate to my TV?

My OS is Ubuntu so if there a specific things I can do it would be really great

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RS232 amd ethernet are completely different on physical level. Actually, on any other level too. So no, you can't just connect it to Ethernet port. But if it's a smart TV, maybe it has actually Ethernet. In fact i can't think of any reason to put RS232 on TV and not to pu Ethernet.

Comment: It's an older TV about 5 years old.
Here is the manual: [Manual](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B_ayS6QBJX3VR2V1X1VxRlloZm8) in page 124 you will find all the details

Comment: The question is, would i look for details... I think your question is already answered.